# Site com framework Quasar não aparece o CSS da Página "<%= productName %>"

Tags: html, css, framework, quasar

Pessoal estou com um projeto com o qual nunca trabalhei com o FrameWork Quasar, tive que aprender em 1 MÊs. Em questão o **SITE NÂO APARECE** e **FICA SOMENTE COM TELA BRANCA**. O projeto tem 2 páginas HTMl, uma própria do quasar e a outra com o CSS e Js que foi feita. Enviei tudo para o FTP, porém quando atualizo aparece somente o contéudo do HTML Quasar "*<%= productName %>*" e não o meu site. O segundo HTMl está numa pasta DISC em SPA. Alguém poderia estar me auxiliando? E**m questão, está como NÃO SEGURO pois ainda tenho que emitir o SSL**
 [HTML Pasta SPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIAaS.jpg)
[Titulo do HTML quasar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVnpd.jpg) 
[Imagem do Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6IeA.jpg)

```
 Código do HTMl da pasta SPA que fiz:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Oita Consórcios</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="description" content="Oi Consórcios">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum- 
     scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="128x128" href="/icons/favicon- 
     128x128.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico">
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-11008635467"> 
    </script>
     <script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
       gtag('js', new Date());
       gtag('config', 'AW-11008635467');</script>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.096e8d00.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.d46c7307.css">
     </head>

     <body>
        <div id=q-app></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: [Já há uma pergunta anterior sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/585542). Para evitar duplicação de informações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui e a postagem fechada, mas se acreditar que tem como adequar a postagem original para [uma dúvida específica sobre desenvolvimento de software](/help), sem entrar em questões de infraestrutura, pode restaurar aquela publicação, e editar. Agora, se a dúvida for sobre configuração de servidor, realmente foge do foco do site.